# Unable to access item inside Url.Action in ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a Ajax call and inside the success function i have a $.each loop.When i try to use dtl it shows me 'The Name dtl doesn't exist in the current context'

### Code

```
$.ajax({
            url: $("#getAllNewsBasicDetails").val(),
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (_newsDetails) {

                $.each(newstype, function (i, dtl) {
                        content = '';

                        content += '<a href="#" class="text-black">' + dtl.NewsTitle + '</a>';
                        content += '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("NewsDetails", "News",new{@NewsId=dtl.NewsId })">'; // In here it shows 'The Name dtl doesn't exist in the current context'
                        content += '</div>';

                    $("#searchItems").prepend(content);
            });
        }
```

Comment: `success function` is ran on client but `Url.Action` - on server.

Comment: @yW0K5o yes but in here i'm unable to assign dtl.NewsId... Is there anyway to use this?

Comment: Using   `content += '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="/News/NewsDetails?NewsId=" + dtl.NewsId.toString() + ">";`  Check my syntax.

Comment: I created a MVC project and get the same error as you are (The Name dtl doesn't exist in the current context). 
The error disappear when I used `content += '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="/News/NewsDetails?NewsId="' + dtl.NewsId.toString() + '">';`
Again it is a mix of client/server functionality. dtl comes from client(html/javascript) and Url.Action comes from server (MVC).

Answer (score 0):

Please change your ajax action as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $("#getAllNewsBasicDetails").val(),
    newsUrl: '@Url.Action("NewsDetails", "News",new{@NewsId=-100000 })',
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (_newsDetails) {

        $.each(newstype, function (i, dtl) {
                var newsUri = newsUrl;              
                content = '';
                content += '<a href="#" class="text-black">' + dtl.NewsTitle + '</a>';
                content += '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="'+ newsUri.replace("-100000", dtl.NewsId)+'">';
                content += '</div>';

            $("#searchItems").prepend(content);
    });
}
```

Comment: Still dtl is not recognized :(

Comment: You need to pass result of Url.Action to success function. I updated my post.Please refer.